# Why don't I have access to the environment. DIRECTORY_PICTURES? (decodeFile returns null)

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I'm trying to get an image stored in the external memory of my Android device

I get the file path in the following way:

```js
 public File getFilePath() {
        File externalFilesDir = actGetImage.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        if (null == externalFilesDir) {return null;}
        return new File(externalFilesDir,"IMG" + ".jpg");
    }
```

In this way the path of the file is:

/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/net.sicoy.sicoybox/files/Pictures/IMG.jpg

To obtain the image I do the following:

```js
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
```

Where path is:

```js
   private File myFile;

   myFile = getFilePath();

   path = myFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

But BitmapFactory.decodeFile (path) returns a value of null and the permissions are enabled:

```js
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: That directory does not exists to begin with. You can check that with File.exists().

Comment: Did you request the permission at run time? This is required on Android versions 6.0 and above. https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: Thanks for answering.
I added the permissions at run time, but the problem persists.

Regarding that the directory does not exist, I am taking a picture with my cell phone and it is the code of another app that I did about a year ago and it works correctly. But with the latest Android studio updates it seems that something is missing.

Comment: Please post the whole source code for logic of decoding Bitmap file.